# How do I create a statement to add additional rows that duplicate the data from already existing rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, recursive-query

Here is a simplified example of what my output currently looks like:

| Name | Month | Year | Filter | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Feb | 2018 | Good! | 10 |
| Bob | Apr | 2018 | Bad | 0 |
| Tom | Dec | 2019 | Good! | 5 |
| Tom | Feb | 2020 | Bad | 0 |
| Sam | Feb | 2018 | Good! | 2 |
| Sam | Apr | 2018 | Bad | 0 |
| Tim | Oct | 2022 | Good! | 50 |
| Tim | Jan | 2023 | Bad | 0 |

My Goal: I'm trying to duplicate any record and apply new months to it if my filter = Good! Within my data, there is gaps between months and I need to have everything in sequential order by month until my filter = bad. Ultimately I need for my output to look like this:

| Name | Month | Year | Filter | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Feb | 2018 | Good! | 10 |
| Bob | Mar | 2018 | Good! | 10 |
| Bob | Apr | 2018 | Bad | 0 |
| Tom | Dec | 2019 | Good! | 5 |
| Tom | Jan | 2020 | Good! | 5 |
| Tom | Feb | 2020 | Bad | 0 |
| Sam | Feb | 2018 | Good! | 2 |
| Sam | Mar | 2018 | Good! | 2 |
| Sam | Apr | 2018 | Bad | 0 |
| Tim | Oct | 2022 | Good! | 50 |
| Tim | Nov | 2022 | Good! | 50 |
| Tim | Dec | 2022 | Good! | 50 |
| Tim | Jan | 2023 | Bad | 0 |

Here is what SQL output looks like exactly: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXeic.png) here I am grouping by LotSysID, VehicleMainSysID, Month Number, YearNumber, and Description. Instead of name in my example output, I am using VehicleMainSysID and LotSysID. Instead of Filter I am using description, bad = Transferred. Good=Retail Inventory.

Essentially, I have data from 2018 up until now and I need to include any gaps of months for when filter = Good! until it equals Bad. There may not even be an additional row where filter = bad, in those cases I would just need to have the data continue to be duplicated until this current month for this current year. NOTE: there is no set start date where all the data begins, depending on the name, the data can start in any month between years 2018-current. I need a dynamic statement where I can create additional rows to fit my business logic.

I've thought of using a recursive statement but was told that it would be incredibly taxing on our server since I'm pulling millions of records through my query.

Comment: Does all the data in 2018 _start_ in the same month? It's impossible to tell from a screenshot of a handful of rows.

Comment: No, depending on the name, the data can start in any single month of any given year.

Comment: And do you really _store_ `February` (in a column called `Date`???) and `2015` in two different columns? Also 2015 is not 2018-current (could be an important detail because, for example, recursion < 100 is usually trivial, but 2015 approaches 100 months ago).

Comment: No it's just an example, for date you can just consider that column name as month. I have a timestamp in my original query that I then format into month and year so I can use the output for my needs later.

Comment: Ok. To get the best help, you should show your original table and true sample data, not some translated form that is halfway there. It's much less confusing that way.

Comment: understood, I gave additional information up above

Comment: Ok, next, [please stop using screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/61305). I know this seems excessive but the things you're doing make it a lot harder than it should be for volunteers to help you solve your problem. [More general tips on asking questions here](https://sqlblog.org/ask).

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm changing everything into tables, is there anything else that would be helpful to include to make it easier? I'm new to posting on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way that finds first month and last month (when the last month has `'Bad'`) for each name, then joins that to a list of *all* months from the earliest date in the data until today, then uses `OUTER APPLY` to find the previous value to determine what to fill the gaps with.

[Working example in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZwSnEeIq) - including the edge case where a person's latest `Filter = 'Good'`.

```
DECLARE @BeginOfMonth date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1));

;WITH Origin AS 
( /* let's get the data and fix the year/month column */
  SELECT Name, Filter, Data, 
    [Month]   = DATEFROMPARTS(YearNumber, MonthNumber, 1),
    LastMonth = MAX(DATEFROMPARTS(YearNumber, MonthNumber, 1)) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY Name)
  FROM dbo.whoknows /* we don't know your table name */
), Agg AS
( /* let's get the first and last month for each name */
  SELECT Name, S = MIN([Month]), E = COALESCE
         (MAX(CASE WHEN [Month] = LastMonth AND Filter = 'Bad' 
         THEN [Month] END), @BeginOfMonth)
  FROM Origin GROUP BY Name
), AllMonths(m) AS
(
  /* let's get ALL the possible months to fill gaps */
  SELECT MIN(s) FROM Agg UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m) FROM AllMonths
  WHERE m < @BeginOfMonth
)
SELECT Agg.Name, 
  [Month] = DATENAME(MONTH, am.m), 
  [Year]  = YEAR(am.m), 
  Filter  = COALESCE(o.Filter, GapFill.Filter),
  Data    = COALESCE(o.Data,   GapFill.Data)
FROM AllMonths AS am 
INNER JOIN Agg ON am.m >= Agg.S AND am.m <= Agg.E
LEFT OUTER JOIN Origin AS o
  ON o.Name = Agg.Name AND o.[Month] = am.m
  OUTER APPLY 
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) org.Filter, org.Data
    FROM Origin AS org
    WHERE org.Name = Agg.Name AND org.[Month] < am.m
    ORDER BY org.[Month] DESC
  ) AS GapFill
ORDER BY Agg.Name, am.m OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

Output:

| Name | Month | Year | Filter | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | February | 2018 | Good! | 10 |
| Bob | March | 2018 | Good! | 10 |
| Bob | April | 2018 | Bad | 0 |
| Sam | February | 2018 | Good! | 2 |
| Sam | March | 2018 | Good! | 2 |
| Sam | April | 2018 | Bad | 0 |
| Tim | October | 2022 | Good! | 50 |
| Tim | November | 2022 | Good! | 50 |
| Tim | December | 2022 | Good! | 50 |
| Tim | January | 2023 | Bad | 0 |
| Tom | December | 2019 | Good! | 5 |
| Tom | January | 2020 | Good! | 5 |
| Tom | February | 2020 | Bad | 0 |